# I accidentally killed the giant horse in BOTW

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

So I was getting the giant horse, as usual, in BOTW post-game on my all shrines save file, and then while I was getting it to the nearest stable to register it, it got killed by a Lynel. Will it respawn? I already tried the horse fairy. It didn’t work because it wasn’t registered. I think I may have tried a blood moon, but it wasn’t there. Is there any way to get it back without restarting my save file?

Answer (score 8):

It appears that all horses will eventually respawn in the local areas where they are originally found, just based on other players' experience.

From a [GameFAQs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75129666):

> I confirmed that you can release the giant or white horse then find
>   them again in their respective places.

And another [GameFAQs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75229231):

> So I released [the giant horse]. Then I checked if it respawns in
>   Taobab Grassland and yes, it does (what a relief).

Answer (score 0):

yes, the giant horse will be there again you just have to wait and do another quest, and then it should be there.it took me a while to get the horse too but I figured it out sorry if this was not helpful

Answer (score -3):

It will eventually respawn. Special horses like the giant horse cannot be revived by the horse god.

Comment: This was already mentioned more than two years ago.

Comment: @Riles Um... Wrigglenite mentioned that the OP already knows that, so you didn't help. Also, I've flagged your comment. This kind of comment is rare and I have no idea how it's still not deleted.

Answer (score -3):

if the giant horse is registered, and it has fallen, Malanya will indeed revive it. Mine got hit by a guardian laser and died at hyrule castle, and I revived it with no problem.

Comment: The OP quite plainly states that the horse was not registered as the horse died on the way to get registered so this does not answer the actual question.